# How to add more buttons into datatable collections side by side

Tags: typescript, collections, datatable

I am trying to create a collection in Typescript, with more than one button on one row. Ideal result would be two buttons on the row.

Now I have this code, which adds buttons into one column:

```
        for (let filterEntry of response) {

        if (filterEntry.defaultFlt == true){
          active = ' btn-primary';
        }
        else {
          active = '';
        }

        table.buttons().button().add(indexOfColection + '-' + buttonIndexInColection ,{
          className: String('btn btn-xs btn-default btn-max dt-button-collection two-column uniqFilterClass ' + active) ,
          text: function (dt, button, config) {
            return filterEntry.name;
          },
          action: (e, dt, node, config) => {
            this.loadFilterData(filterEntry.id);    
            this.activateButton(node);              
          }
        });

        buttonIndexInColection++;
      }
```

Does anyone knows, how to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this problem whithout another button. I added to button's name small object:

```
'<i class="fa fa-times fa-fw delete-class"></i>'
```

When somebody click on this object. I catch this click by event and by unique class name: **delete-class**. Then recognize, if this click was on this object.
That's it. Good luck.